# How to convert singleton array to a scalar value in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have 1x1x1x1x... array and wish to convert it to scalar?

How do I do it?

`squeeze` does not help.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1]])
s = np.squeeze(matrix)
print type(s)
print s

matrix = [[1]]
print type(s)
print s

s = 1
print type(s)
print s
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use the `item()` function:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[[[7]]]])
print(matrix.item())
```

**Output**

```
7
```

Answer (score 23):

Numpy has a function explicitly for this purpose: [asscalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html)

```
>>> np.asscalar(np.array([24]))
24
```

This uses `item()` in the [implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/lib/type_check.py#L461-L482).

I guess `asscalar` was added to more explicit about what's going on.

**Update:**

As of 2023 this function has been removed from NumPy (see [v1.23 release notes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.23.0-notes.html)).

Comment: Note though that as of numpy 1.16 this is deprecated: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html

Answer (score 9):

You can index with the empty tuple after squeezing:

```
x = np.array([[[1]]])
s = np.squeeze(x)  # or s = x.reshape(())
val = s[()]
print val, type(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) -

```
np.take(matrix,0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: matrix = np.array([[67]])

In [16]: np.take(matrix,0)
Out[16]: 67

In [17]: type(np.take(matrix,0))
Out[17]: numpy.int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> float(np.array([[[[1]]]]))
1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the numpy.flatten() function to flatten the array to a one dimensional array.
For instance:

```
s = [[1]]
print(s[0][0])
>>>> 1
```

or

```
a=[[1],[2]]
print(a[0][0])
>>>> 1
print(a[1][0])
>>>> 2
```