# Trouble getting the actual value of numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array as follows-

```
test= [['test1' 'human,cow' 'human,cow' 'human,cow']
 ['test2' 'wheat,mouse' 'wheat,mouse' 'wheat,mouse']
['test3' 'wallaby,mouse' 'wallaby,mouse' 'wallaby,mouse']]
```

When I'm trying to get the array value, for example  `test[0,1]`, I get `array(['human,cow'], dtype='<U13')`. How do I get the actual value `human,cow` instead of `array[], dtype=` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert singleton array to a scalar value in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157742/how-to-convert-singleton-array-to-a-scalar-value-in-python)

Comment: @jdehesa I had tried `item()` function but it did not work. I was unaware of `asscalar` function. Thank you.

Comment: what's the `test.shape`

Comment: No repro. `test = np.array([['test1', 'human,cow', 'human,cow', 'human,cow'], ['test2', 'wheat,mouse', 'wheat,mouse', 'wheat,mouse'], ['test3', 'wallaby,mouse', 'wallaby,mouse', 'wallaby,mouse']])` followed by `print(test[0, 1])` prints 'human,cow', as expected. Its type is `numpy.str`. Numpy 1.15.